# Preg replace for particular a href

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I just want to convert the absolute server to relative url using `preg_replace()`. But my regex knowledge is zero. How can I do this?

Example:

```
<a href="http://mysite.localhost.com/admin/structure">Some text</a>
```

to

```
<a href="/admin/structure">Some text </a>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you really have to use regex for all of this?

Comment: Could you do a simple replace instead if you know it's always the same?

Comment: In my content, there might be a lot of <a> tags. Whatever the <a> tags consist mysite.localhost.com I want to convert it as relative URL

Comment: Even you don't need php for that you can replace with javascript

Comment: No. I just want to do in php only

Comment: https://eval.in/473165

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a lot quicker using PHP's [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function. i.e.:

```
$href = str_replace('http://mysite.localhost.com', '', $href);
```

An advantage being that str_replace() places far less overhead on the server compared to preg_replace().

Comment: I just want to add this for <a> only. Now it is applying for <img> also. Any help?

Comment: @Kiwi use 2 variables, like $a_href and $img_href. Only do the str_replace on $a_href

Answer (score 0):

This will turn every absolute link in an `<a>` tag into a relative link:

```
<?php

$html = '<a href="http://mysite.localhost.com/admin/structure">Some text</a>';

echo preg_replace('#<a ([^\>]+)href=["\']?https?://[^/]+(/[^\s]+)["\']?([^\>]+)>#i', '<a $1href="$2"$3>', $html);
```

returns `<a href="/admin/structure">Some text</a>`